# ERROR in Cannot read property 'annotation' of null - Angular 5

Tags: angular, error-handling

When I start my Angular project with `ng serve -aot`, it compiles fine, but when I make some changes in project files and save (angular then recompiles), cmd throws the following error:

> ERROR in Cannot read property 'annotation' of null

If I run the project with `ng serve`, it compiles and recompiles fine.

I believe I should find a way how to get a more discriptive error and go from there, but don't know how. Any tips would be much appreciated!

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: can you please paste your full error message.

Comment: That's the full message

Comment: Usually angular indicates also a file, a node module name or a component, does the error contains such info? Maybe it's in another row of the error stack, but there should be this information

Comment: If `Annotation` is a property of a your custom class, check if somewhere the class is just declared but not initialized

Comment: I don't have a custom class with annotation property, I believe it is a property of angular compiler, or something like that...

Comment: Strange... Are you using an explicit webpack.config file? (please, answer to my comment by "tagging" me with "@Deadpool", otherwise I don't receive any notification of your replies). If the answer is yes, then you should give a look to [webpack node externals plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals). Maybe the compiler considers also node_modules folder.

Comment: How can I check if I am using explicit webpack.config file? @Deadpool

Comment: You can see it in your project root folder. It should be named "webpack.config.js" or something strictly similar, but if you are developing an angular-cli v.6 or more app, then the file shouldn't be there by default, unless you don't use the command ng eject. But if there isn't an explicit webpack configuration, I suggest you not to do ng eject

Comment: @Deadpool I do not have "webpack.config.js" in my root folder (by root folder you mean the folder where package.json is right?)

Comment: It could be the same where package.json is or the folder immediatly before that. But if you don't have webpack.config, i don't have any idea... Does the error occurred after installing anew package? Maybe is there a problem of versions? [I've tried to help another user yesterday who had a similar issue, take a look at the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677125/cannot-read-property-write-of-undefined#comment88371907_50677125)

Comment: @Deadpool my bad, I do have webpack.config.js file, but acctually it's inside node_modules/xxhashjs folder -> which I don't know what it's purpose

Comment: Regarding the stackoverflow issue you linked... should I update the CLI? @Deadpool

Comment: For the first comment: No, it's not the same webpack.config that I intended. If you're using an angular cli, the webpack configuration is embedded inside the angular cli. For the second one: I don't know if you have to update the cli, it depends of what package causes the issue. Sometimes, it's the package to be updated or the module or the cli even needs to be downgraded but you can give a try with updating the cli. To be sure of what needs to be updated, you can run `npm outdate` where you've got package.json. It will show you any out-of-date module

Comment: @Deadpool I've updated all outdated packages... and the error is still the same

Comment: @Deadpool Do you have any clue how could I get a more discriptive error message?

Comment: Uhm... I don't know... By logic, it's a node package issue. Maybe it needs another one or maybe it uses uncompatible libraries, as - for example - bootstrap 4 uses JQuery. If the error started after installing a node package, i would try to uninstall it and see if it runs. If it runs, try to reinstall it and see if after npm install, the console tells you some alert. If it still don't run or it's another package or *(continue on next comment)*

Comment: or maybe it's something else. By a quick look, Annotations are like `@Component` or `@NgModule` in angular ([source](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/03/the-difference-between-annotations-and-decorators.html)). I've been reading from a while that decorators are going to be modified on future angular versions. But it shouldn't be on version 6.x.x. So... Mhh.. Maybe you've wrote some annotation in a wrong way in some app module or component? But being honestly, I am not sure on what it could be

Comment: Another theory...If you've updated from angular 5 to angular 6, maybe it could be that you've missed something which now is deprecated(? maybe). Give a look to [this](https://update.angular.io/) and [this](https://academind.com/learn/angular/snippets/angular-6-whats-new-angular-upgrade/). More than this... I don't know... Sorry :/

Comment: @Deadpool I'm still on angular 5 -> 5.2.9, by the way thank you for help :) I will try to figure out which package is causing me error, I guess there is no easy/fast way to figure that out...

Comment: Mhh... Maybe angular is too out-of-date and some package new versions requires angular 6? By the way, you're welcome!

Comment: Any confirmed/verified solution found for this yet?